# Rails: Loop through db objects according to model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models `post.rb` and `attachment.rb` with the following associations:

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post, optional: true
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attachments, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

This is what I have inside the controller action where the view is:

```
 def results_search
    if params[:search]
      @attachment = Attachment.all
      @posts = Post.search(params[:search])
   end
 end
```

I'm trying to do this `<% @posts.attachments.each do |post|%>` but I'm getting the following error `undefined method attachments' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fa673bef9d0>`

I want to loop through all the results from the search (`@posts`) and show the results alongside the attachments that belong to each post. Each attachment has a `post_id` assigned to it. Any ideas how I can implement this?

Comment: I'm trying todo this `<% @posts.attachments.each do |post|%>` but I'm getting the following error `undefined method attachments' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fa673bef9d0>`

Comment: `attachments` is an *instance method*. `@posts` is *collection* (of the `ActiveRecord_Relation` flavor). You can't call an instance method on a collection! You have to call an instance method on an instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to want to do something like:

```
@posts.each do |post|
  # do some stuff with post (show name, content, etc.)
  post.attachments.each do |attachment|
    # do stuff with attachment (show, etc.)
  end
end
```

What it *really* looks like depends on where you're doing this (view?) and what tools you're using (vanilla erb, slim, haml, etc.).

Also, you're going to want to do some eager loading so you don't end up in N+1 land.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jvillian... for some reason the image don't appear.  It doesn't return an error though! Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: That sounds like a different problem/question. But, this one is solved, I suppose?

Comment: You should open a new question, show code, etc. I'll keep an eye out for it.

Comment: You definitely should do `@posts = Post.search(params[:search]).includes(:attachments)` to avoid the N + 1 query problem.